# YouTube API forbids caching/saving videos. How does McTube do it?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, app-store

As everyone using the YouTube api knows, saving or caching youtube files is prohibited by the google terms of service. So how then does [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mctube-for-youtube/id652124176?mt=8) app [McTube] allow users to cache videos? I googled around and apparently google reportedly told them to remove the feature. Yet a year later the feature is still there. What gives, and how can I as a developer incorporate such a feature in my app without getting kicked off the app store?

Thanks for your time  :)

Comment: Ask for a higher quota. I know that's not the answer you were hoping for but, it's just about all you can do unless you get permission from them.

Comment: @Jonathan I understand that's the best way to go about it if my goal is to reduce the quota used. What if my goal is to allow the user to (as an example) play 4-5 videos offline? To be clear I would not allow these videos to be shared at all, specifically for offline viewing within my app and nowhere else. Not possible right?  :(

Comment: I am not able to answer your question. You would need to contact Google or someone on the YouTube team. I am also facing the same problem as you are. I apologize but, my above comment is all the advice that I can give.

Comment: No problem. I must mention that, I am not your lawyer or Google's lawyer and I'm not a lawyer at all. This communication does not establish a client-lawyer relationship. Good luck on your project though!